# has_many associations brings up "undefined method"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many

Beeing a real newbie, I am building a very simple ticketsystem with RoRs.

A Ticket can have a status in a states table (such as "confirmed" with an ID of "1") which I want to connect via associations. I want to show the status in a view. The code is below. But I keep getting an undefined method error. Maybe I set up the associations in a wrong way?

Ticket.rb:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :state
```

state.rb:

```
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tickets
```

index.html.erb (basically the scaffolding):

```
<% @tickets.each do |ticket| %>

<tr>
<td><%= ticket.caller %></td>
<td><%= ticket.supervisor %></td>
<td><%= ticket.subject %></td>
<td><%= ticket.name %></td>
<td><%= ticket.email %></td>
<td><%= ticket.state.status %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Anzeigen', ticket %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Bearbeiten', edit_ticket_path(ticket) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Löschen', ticket, confirm: 'Sind Sie sicher?', method: :delete %></td>
```

tickets_controller.rb

```
@tickets = Ticket.search(params[:search]).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

Here´s the SQL-Query it creates:

```
State Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
```

This brings up the following error:

```
undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass
```

Interestingly enough, it seems to work in the rails console:
`1.9.3-p194 :016 > @tickets.state
    State Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "states".* FROM "states" WHERE "states"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
 => #<State id: 2, status: "confirmed", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
1.9.3-p194 :017 > @tickets.state.status
 => "confirmed"`

Comment: Is ticket defined correctly? This error usually means that state is returning empty. Does just `<&= ticket.attribute %>` work correctly?

Comment: Also could you post your exact code for the view?

Comment: Yes, I get all attributes of ticket but none of state. If I do ticket.state it throws me: `<State:0xb601695c>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Rails' console to see if each ticket has a `State` object defined. It could be returning `nil`, making the `status` method undefined.

Comment: Good idea. Only one item has a state right now. I just added it and all the older testobjects don't have no state. Will try tmr back in the office.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a reference in your databse, create a migration:

```
class AddStateAndUserToTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    change_table :tickets do |t|
      t.references :state
      t.references :user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok, the problem is your association! I will edit my answer to put the solution.

Comment: I think I have them referenced correctly. The user table works (it was however created by Devise). This is the migration I used. Does t.references add something else?

`class AddStateidToTickets < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
    change_table :tickets do |t|
      add_column :tickets, :state_id, :integer
    end
  end
end`

Comment: You can try two things: Add `include(:states)` in your search, somethin like `Ticket.include(:states).all` and try to get the attributes of states objects or open your rails console to get the Tickets and debug whats happening.

Comment: You make the same call in console and in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this is a simple data problem... one of your tickets has no state. execute a query on the database to confirm this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tickets t 
 LEFT JOIN states s ON t.state_id = s.id
 WHERE s.id IS NULL
```